# How do you express trigonometric identites in simplest form, e.g. $\frac{2\sec(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Are there strict rules defining what the "simplest" form of a trigonometric identity is? For example, $\dfrac{2\sec(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$ can also be expressed as $\dfrac{2\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ [ignoring restrictions on $x$].

Which one, if either of these forms, is "simpler," and why?

Comment: The rule of thumb employed by computer algebra software (such as *Mathematica*) seems to be 1) the smallest number of trigonometric functions, then 2) the smallest number of arguments (e.g., $\theta$s throughout is better than $\theta$ and $2 \theta$ and $\theta/2$...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Does rule 2 apply to the functions themselves too? If not, doesn't that mean that sin(x) and 1/csc(x) have the same "degree" of simplification?

Comment: Don't know for sure.